# Creating Virtual Environment

Tags: django, windows, virtualenv, project, virtualenvwrapper

I have completed a project in Django on my Windows PC without creating a virtual env. Now, I feel I should have a virtual env.

Please, do explain to me in steps to create a virtualenvwrapper and put my project into the same.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you can create virtual environment using the command,

python -m venv .venv(virtual_env_name)

In your project directory, run
**python -m venv .venv**

To activate your virtual environment, run

**.venv\Scripts\activate**

And install your packages inside virtual env